# Wrote a Python code to retrieve coordinates and write them on a csv file, the is made but is empty, not even the headers are added

Tags: python, csv, logging, raspberry-pi, gps

I used a code that retrieves coordinates via a GPS chip and writes it on a csv file. The csv file is made but is empty on every run. This is my first time coding with Python so can't really get my head around the problem.

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep, strftime, time
import serial
import pynmea2
import datetime
from csv import writer

#setup the serial port to which gps is connected 
port = "/dev/ttyS0"
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.5)
dataout  = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
counter = 0

def get_sense_data():
    while True:
        newdata = ser.readline()
        if newdata[0:6] == '$GPGGA':
            parsed_line = pynmea2.parse(newdata)
            latitude_reading = parsed_line.latitude
            alpha = latitude_reading
            longitude_reading = parsed_line.longitude
            beta = longitude_reading
            sense_data=[]
            sense_data.append(counter)
            sense_data.append(datetime.datetime.now())
            sense_data.append(alpha)
            sense_data.append(beta)
            return sense_data

with open('GPSdata.csv', 'w+') as f:
    data_writer = writer(f)
    data_writer.writerow(['Term No.','Date and Time','Latitude','Longitude'])
    while True:
        data = get_sense_data()
        data_writer.writerow(data)
        counter = counter + 1
```

I also tried to change the indents a little bit, but the csv file still comes out empty

Comment: `import os` and `print(os.path.exists('GPSdata.csv'))`

Comment: how can i integrate it into this code, isn't csv library notation different here. ( sorry im a complete noob at this so a little more explanation is needed)

Answer (score 2):

You code looks generally correct, but since you never close or flush the file in the infinite while loop, the file may be written slowly enough that it hasn't flushed to disk yet.

Here's a simplified version of your code with an added flush.  If you run this script without stopping it and look at the CSV content, you'll see it add a line every second.  Remove the flush and it may be blank for a long time...at least until the OS decides it is time to flush the buffer to disk itself.

```
#!python2
from csv import writer
import time

counter = 0

with open('GPSdata.csv', 'wb') as f:
    data_writer = writer(f)
    data_writer.writerow(['Term No.','Date and Time','Latitude','Longitude'])
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        data = [counter,2,3,4]
        data_writer.writerow(data)
        print(data)
        f.flush()
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: The file is made but no data is stored in it, not even the headers

Comment: @Ajdar did you add the flush after writerow in your code?  Did you try my exact example with and without the flush? There could be other problems with your code, but it is not a [mcve].

Comment: Add some print lines to your code to see if it is even looping correctly and receiving data.  You definitely need the flush, however.

Comment: added print into the data, the data is being recieved correctly. The problem is writing in the file. I used the exact copy of your example. i got a few error    1.) the newline=' ' was caught in a syntax error, so had to delete it . whereas the rest of the code was fine. but still the file was empty

Comment: @Ajdar So you are using Python 2 then.  I've updated my sample for Python 2.  Try it **exactly**.  Do not integrate it into your code yet.  `newline=''` is correct usage for opening a `csv` file in Python 3.  `'wb'` is correct use for Python 2.  Are you sure you aren't stuck in the `while True:` loop in `get_sense_data()`?  If you aren't even getting the header, your code isn't getting to the flush().